# What's the correct scheduling of calling C functions of a Simulink model after Simulink Coder conversion?

Tags: simulink

I've used Simulink to build a subsystem and converted it into C using Simulink Coder. Then I will write my main function where the subsystem's C functions (mdlOutput(), mdlUpdate(), etc) will be called, as follows:

```
/* scheduling 1*/
main()
{
...  
for (i=0;i<100;i++)
{
   mdlOutput();
   mdl_U = 1-mdl_Y; /* updating input using output */
   mdlUpdate();
}
...
}
```

You can see that a feedback is formed in the main function. However, I've seen many examples where mdl_U is put ahead of mdlOuput(), like:

```
/* scheduling 2*/
main()
{
...
for (i=0;i<100;i++)
{
   mdl_U = 1-mdl_Y; /* updating input using output */
   mdlOutput();  
   mdlUpdate();
 }
...
}
```

Above two schedulings give different results. I'm wondering which one is correct? Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as if you have selected an S-Function target for your code generation. If you intend to run the code on a generic processor, I would suggest the grt target.

Simulation -> Model Configuration Parameters -> Code Generation -> System Target File should be set appropriately. A good starting point is grt.tlc or ert.tlc.

When code is generated, you will see the following functions:

1. `<model_name>_initialize` - This function should be called once prior to entering your scheduling loop
2. `<model_name>_step` - If you have multiple task rates in your model, there may be several of these functions. These should be called in your target code at the same rate that they execute in the model.
3. `<model_name>_terminate` - This function should be called prior to shutting down your target (although, in alot of cases, this can be empty)

[This Matlab help page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/ug/generating-code-using-simulink-coder.html) might be a good starting point to research further.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy. I'm using _grt_ target, not _s-function_ target. The _step_ function is actually a combination of _output_ and _update_ functions (_output_ first, then _update_). Therefore, your scheduling is actually equivalent to scheduling 2 in my question.